# React Native Firebase onAuthStateChanged with conditional rendering give warning Can't perform a React state update

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

React Native app on close and reopen, gives Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. It seems my conditional rendering is causing this and if I remove the splash screen part then it's fine.

`renderScreens()` below for splash screen when Firebase connection is establishing before rendering the stack. This works but I keep getting warning to cleanup in useEffect function.

```
if (auth.initializing) {
  return <RootStack.Screen name={'Splash'} component={SplashScreen} />;
}
return auth.user && !auth.loading ? (
  <RootStack.Screen name={'MainStack'} component={MainStackNavigator} />
) : (
  <RootStack.Screen name={'AuthStack'} component={AuthStackNavigator} />
);
```

In my auth hooks

```
const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState<boolean>(true);
const [user, setUser] = useState<FirebaseAuthTypes.User | null>(null);

useEffect(() => {
  auth().onAuthStateChanged(userState => {
    setUser(userState);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  });
}, []);
```

Tried doing `unmount` trick and didn't help. Below is the example from react-native-firebase

```
// Handle user state changes
  function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);
```

On app open, there's always a short delay while getting the auth.user object, if splash screen is removed, then it's weird to have authenticated user to see the auth screen and then immediately after user object is loaded to change to main app. How can I properly handle this and not causing the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the warning part for now but one thing to avoid this: `if splash screen is removed, then it's weird to have authenticated user to see the auth screen` is to store the users details in some sort of localstorage. I cant remember the react native equivalent of `localstorage` but in my React app I do this:

`const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUser')))`

where I pull the user straight from `localstorage`. this resolved the "flicker" I was seeing where logged in users would see the login screen briefly as `onAuthStateChanged` takes longer to kick in.

You can then delete `localStorage` when the user logs out. ah I just remembered it's `AsyncStorage`. It will be possible to achieve the same functionality in that: https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage

let me know if you need any more help!

Comment: I'm using AsyncStorage for the later authenticed user profile part. But I thought Firebase Authentication already implemented it's own local storage? Whenever I call `onAuthStateChange` it's pulling the user object saved locally?